# XSL-FO: Render an element which stretches from the current position to the end of current line

Tags: pdf-generation, xsl-fo

I have an application which stores data in xml and generates PDF using xsl-fo.

I'm trying to find out is there a way to render an element with a width from the last element position to the end of current line. For example:

(page left)***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__**(page right)

```
       blablablablabla[      our element      ]
       blablablablablablablablablablablablablab
       blablablablablablablablablablablablablab
       blabl[           our element           ]
       blablablablablablablablablablablablablab
       blablablablablablablablablablablablablab
```

Can anyone share some examples of how can this be implemented?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't think this is posible in a fluid layout, but a don'treally know much about [XSL-FO Vocabulary](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `fo:leader` to add stretchable space:

```
<fo:block text-align-last="justify">
 blablablablabla[<fo:leader/>our element<fo:leader/>]
</fo:block>
<fo:block text-align-last="justify">
 blabl[<fo:leader/>our element<fo:leader/>]
</fo:block>
```

Comment: as far as I understand this solution forces us to use separate fo:blocks for each such element. But I have 1 block of text (with all blablabla's and 2 stratchable elements, where each should stretch to the end of current line).. Or.. maybe I miss smth?

Comment: @Andrey: maybe I'm the one missing something...:-) But I took for granted that each line in the layout that you want must be a fo:block. It's hard to see how you could do it any other way.

Comment: but it seems to me that I've found a way out:
 <xsl:template match="element">       
  <fo:leader leader-pattern="rule"></fo:leader>
  <fo:block />
 </xsl:template>
:D

Comment: @Andrey: It's hard for me to comment on your "way out", since I know nothing about your real problem. I have no idea what "blabla" and "[ our element ]" actually represent. But I think I provided a reasonable answer based on the available information.